# android push notification is failing with these message any one have solution for this

Tags: php, android, push-notification

```
 $registrationIds=array("My Key");
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => array
(
    'message'=>'here is a message. message',

)
);
 $key="1234444";
$headers = array
(
    'Authorization:key='.$key,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
return $result;
```

Output:

{ multicast_id: 7750113442176841000, success: 0, failure: 1, canonical_ids: 0, results: [ { error: "MismatchSenderId" } ] }

Answer (score 0):

My Working Code:

```
 function send_push_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {


    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    //print_r($headers);
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Your code is right. Are you using right project id?

Comment: am not using project id

Comment: SENDER_ID is your project id. You will get this id when you create API of your project on https://code.google.com/apis/console/. After starting "Google Cloud Messaging for android" service, you have to copy project id from URL "https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:xxxxxxxxxxxxx" where "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" will be your project id. For example: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"= 660866775559. Now use this sender id to register your device. for testing purpose you may use chrome postman plugin and pass required parameter in php device "register" function with URL.

Answer (score 0):

Given the error you have described, you are not using the right `SENDER_ID` key.

The right `SENDER_ID` to use is your project number in your developers website:

`https://console.developers.google.com/project/XXXXXXX/apiui/credential?authuser=0`

that XXXXXX is the sender id key you have to use to send your push notificationes.

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)